# Can't ping gateway

Tags: networking, router

I have a Verizon Westell modem/router. I have a Linksys router plugged into it. I had a DMZ set to the linksys. I disabled it, and i have lost it on the network. The linksys is now set to DHCP, and it is on line. The IP of the router is now 192.168.1.18, and the gateway is 192.168.1.1. I cannot ping that address, and I cannot log on to the web portal on it. Pretty confused.

Comment: A pretty confusing description of the issue, too. Can you elaborate a bit? What Linksys model are you dealing with? What do you mean by "had a DMZ set to the linksys"?

Comment: It is a linksys model WRT54G2. I had a DMZ host in the westell set to 192.168.1.200. I had previously set the router to a static IP of 192.168.1.200 with a gateway of 192.168.1.1. I took out the DMZ host, and lost the ability to "see" the westell(no ping from a computer on the network, or from the router itself). The router is now set to obtain automatically, and can get out to the internet. Also, I have run a tracert from a computer on the network to www.google.com, and I go through 192.168.1.1 before I get out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably the Verizon and Linksys bits are both using the same subnet. With that happening, when you try to go to 192.168.1.1, it doesn't know where to go and is confused, so it errors out.

I've had this sort of problem before, years ago, when I had a wired router, then added a wireless onto it as a wireless access point. Basically, you have to make sure DHCP is turned off on one or both routers and set the linksys to something other than 192.168.1.x, such as 192.168.2.x

Comment: The linksys local IP is set to 205.1.1.100.

Comment: 205.1.1.100 is not a private IP address. Are you sure that is the correct address you should be using? Read RFC1918 http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html